# Using static block to allocate resources in java

Tags: java

Is it a bad practice to open resources such as database connection etc in static field of a class.

```
class ClassName {
    static {
        //open database connection
    }
}
```

Note: I am not using the same resource in multiple classes. It's used in atmost one class only.

I am doing this, basically to ensure that the program does not fail mid away through, due to error in resource allocation.

Edit : I am new to application development(trainee). I have read most of the previous answers and could not find anything related to the question i have asked (good practices).

Comment: Where will you close the resources you opened?

Comment: we use a static method to create a connection to DB. its much cleaner and faster than having a connection created per object created.

Comment: is it ok or a bad practice. I am new to application development(trainee now)

Comment: It is bad practice. For one, if something goes wrong with the connection (or, simply, you close it) and you need to reinitialize it, you can't re-invoke the static block. For another, you can't unit test that class without it opening a connection to your database.

Answer (score 3):

This is definitely bad practice.

Keep in mind that *static* is an abnormality to good OO design (in the end, *static* translates to procedural programming in disguise).

In other words: you don't want something so essential as preparing your database setup happening in some static initialisier. Meaning: most likely you should add certain abstractions to your classes do not depend directly upon such code.

Beyond that: what happens if you figure at one point that you need certain levels of control? That will be almost impossible if those "resources" are statically owned by your classes.

And of course: if your classes rely on static code ... you render them "hard" (well, almost impossible) to unit-test by default. Not using *static* is like lesson number one in "how to create testable code" school.